# Do 'higher tier' cars give better stats?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

So I've been using the Nissan GTR Egoist for the whole game so far and have unlocked all the mods on it and all the pro mods.

I recently got the Porsche spyder 918 concept and I'm curious to know that if I unlock all the mods on this car, or similarly any of the Most Wanted list cars, will they give better overall stats when upgraded or are all the cars similar?

Comment: What do you mean by 'or are all the cars similar'?

Comment: If a car you gain access to at the start of the game, say the Nissan GTR has 40 speed, and you mod it up to 60. Would the Porsche you unlock by beating and shutting it down have a base of 50 and be moddable to 80 or are all cars similar spec?
In essence is it worth me doing races for unlocked cars to get mods, or should I stick with the same car the whole time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every car is slightly different in comparison to every other car, but unlocking the upgrades will further differentiate the cars from each other.

It's true that some of the cars have similar stats, a lot of cars have similar levels of acceleration or top speeds in their default state. Unlocking the upgrades from the races will provide bonuses and choices - for example you're not going to use both long and short gears or lightweight chassis and reinforced chassis at the same time since these options are mutually exclusive to each other.

The cars gained from completing Most Wanted races are already improved from their base stats and generally more prestigious cars anyway so these are an improvement over most, if not all, of the other cars in their base state - but a lot of this is down to handling and if you can drive one particular car well you'll generally always do better than driving a faster car or a lighter car.

Comment: Looks like the Hennessey Venom GT from the DLC is the 'best' car, having unlocked all it's mods now it has the highest stats. http://www.venomgt.com/

Answer (score 0):

No car is the same. Every car has some advantages and disadvantages. Some have better handling, some have better speeds. Some have worse acceleration, etc.